# Is there an absolute minimum intensity level to the stimuli we can perceive?

Tags: perception, psychophysics

By stimuli that we can perceive, I mean what our five senses can perceive.

Is there an absolute minimum for humans, or can we "train" ourselves to perceive stimuli at lower intensity?

And if there is an absolute minimum intensity, do we know what its value is?

Comment: Why the downvote? Downvoting without commenting is useless.

Comment: downvoting without comment is the best.

Comment: i think absolute lower limit is defined by chemical bonds energy and activation energy of enzymes. For eye, for example, lowest energy of photons that produce visual response is somewhere around 750nm

Comment: @aandreev - The title mentions 'perception' and Matt asks about training as well. Chemical bonds are far away from perception, and cannot be changed with training. This question is about the perceptual level I guess.

Comment: You should specify what kind of perception you are interested in. Though the voltage threshold for action potential may be more or less same for all neurons, the different neuromodulators and other modulatory neurons (interneurons) would affect different neural paths differently.

Comment: @AliceD I think any discussion about votes should go on meta. Also, perception has very defined (in some known cases) chemical&physical basis. Leaving it out and talking only about what people measure/observe is tangential to the question IMHO. Physics of transduction is the ultimate barrier for perception.

Comment: @aandreev - we might continue this on chat, but just shortly - eventually the way to measure perception thresholds is by asking subjects if they perceive a certain threshold stimulus yes/no. Going to the test tube isn't perception and more importantly, the ultimate bottleneck determining the threshold isn't the question I think?

Comment: @AliceD chat is fine. My line of thought is following: between cognitive perception (or any other observable manifestation of excitation by stimulus) there are several layers of amplification and inhibition. Each of which might be optimized (in principle). The only true limit _to my taste_ is around energy of chemical interactions. Or maybe I am off the course of OP's thoughts

Comment: @aandreev,  I would consider answering the question then, it sounds plausible. Bio.SE Often answers questions, but often lacks multiple answers. Mine hasn't been accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are limits to what a sensory system can detect, which is called the **detection threshold**. To determine the detection threshold *psychophysical* methods can be used. A straightforward way to determine the detection threshold is with a *yes/no task*, where the subject receives stimuli with various intensities. An arbitrary point, mostly the 50% correct-rate, is then defined as the detection threshold. At this point, the subject correctly detects the stimulus 50% of the times. The response curve in a psychophysical task typically takes the shape of a cumulative function such as the one shown in Fig. 1.

Hence, the detection threshold is an arbitrary point, because people are not machines and show variability in their decisions. The detection limit of, e.g., electronic devices is much more precisely defined. The exact values of the detection limits depend on the exact stimulus (visual, tactile etc.) and depend highly on the exact stimulus. For example, in the visual domain the detection limit of light depends on the color, the location in the retina tested, dark adaptation etc etc, and in the tactile domain static pressure stimuli have a different threshold than vibratory, different body parts have different thresholds etc. etc.

[image: psychometric curve]
<sup>Fig. 1. Psychometric curve showing 50% threshold of a visual stimulus. source: [Webvision](http://webvision.med.utah.edu/book/part-viii-gabac-receptors/psychophysics-of-vision/)</sup>

Training to lower the detection threshold (i.e. improve detection limits) is indeed possible ([Sterr et al., 1998](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/18/11/4417.full)).

**Reference**
[Sterr et al., *J Neurosci* (1998), **18**: 4417-23](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/18/11/4417.full)